# java wont catch OutOfBounds exception

Tags: java

The out of bounds exception isn't being shown and my code still runs

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class pr50
{
   static String[] arr;
   static int modes;
   static int old;
   static int[] nums; 

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("pr50.dat"));
      int limit = in.nextInt();
      in.nextLine();
      for(int x = 0; x < limit; x++)
      {
         arr = in.nextLine().split(" ");
         nums = new int[arr.length];
         for(int b  = 0; b < arr.length; b++)
         {
            nums[b] = Integer.valueOf(arr[b]);
         }
         Arrays.sort(nums);
         old = 0;
         modes = 0;
         for(int y = 0; y < nums.length; y++)
         {
            int current = nums[y];
            for(int c = 0; current == nums[y+c] && nums[y+c] < nums.length ; c++)
            {
               if(old < 1)
                  modes++;
               else
                  old++;
               current = nums[y+x];
            }
         }
         if(modes > 1)
            System.out.println(modes + " MODES");
         else
            System.out.println(modes + " MODE");
      }
   }
}
```

Here's a sample file:

```
2
56 77 66 22 33 55 66 66 66 
80 93 87 72 80 77 43 87 98 99 100
```

Comment: Yep. That's some code alright. So where do you think the problem is?

Comment: If it runs, then there's no exception. Give sample input that actually throws an exception

Comment: In the second iteration of your loop `current == nums[y+c]` will be false and the `for` loop will terminate.  The will be no chance for the OOB Exception to be thrown.

Comment: On my teacher's computer, it catches that error using the same code

Comment: Well, then, your teacher's computer had better be telling you more than just "Out of bounds" (like at least what line number) or it's gonna be pretty tough to debug.

Comment: speaking of debugging is natural for the debugger not to show local variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is right here:

```
for(int c = 0; current == nums[y+c] && nums[y+c] < nums.length ; c++)
```

Think about this, the loop will run at least onece only if nums[y+c]
means nums[y] < nums.length but if in your array, the largest element is more than or equals the length of array, it will never consider `nums[y+1]`, let's try:

```
1
1 2 3     //lenght = 3
2 MODES
```

Because at the largest element, 3 < 3 is fail, it will not run `nums[y+1]` at the next time loop, but if you type:

```
1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1   //lenght = 7
```

last element is 1 and 1 < 7, the loop will run next loop and check nums[6+1]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
```

So to make it throw `OutOfBoundsException`, the largest element must be less than the length of line (Mean number of elements)!

```
run:
1
0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at test.main(test.java:30)
C:\Users\Fes Nguyen\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: Sorry because I have to edit my answer a lot of time :D, I am newbie!.